# Constraint for matrix representation for general irreducible permutation group.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, representation-theory

Say I have a matrix $\bf P$ for which is ensured that $P_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$. Then consider this requirement:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\bf P}^k[1,0,\dots,0]^T = [1,1,\dots,1]$$

Should this be enough to make $\bf P$ a fully reduced permutation matrix?

If I write another requirement

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\bf PC}^k[1,0,\dots,0]^T = [1,1,\dots,1]$$

where $\bf C$ is a matrix representation for some generator of the cyclic group $C_n$. Would this also do?

Comment: If your matrices are supposed to have entries in $\{0,1\}$ then you should make that clear from the start, not at the very end in a «note»... It completely changes the question!

Comment: In any case, for the initial question: you can take $P$ to be any matrix which maps $[1,0,\dots,0]$ to $[0,1,1,\dots,1]$ and this last vector to zero.

Comment: By the way, I guess that «I assume that I have some mechanism to ensure that $P_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}$» is just a long way of saying «Suppose that $P_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i$ and $j$.» Similarly, the normal way of saying «Should this be enough of a requirement to make P a blah?» is «Does tthis imply that $P$ is a blah?»

Comment: And for the second question, we simply need $P$ mapping $[1,\ldots,1]$ to itself (say $P[1,0,\ldots,0]^T=[1,1,0,\ldots,0]^T$, $P[0,1,0,\ldots,0]^T=0$, and $P$ fixes all other canonical base elements.

Comment: I don't get it. Sorry. Maybe I am being tired.